# How can I export multiple candidates from Indeed?

Tags: indeed

I'm trying to export my list of Indeed job candidates, however, following their help article, as well as other blogs, I seem to be missing the export button.

from: https://indeed.force.com/employerSupport1/s/article/360026204071?language=en_US

> **To export candidates for a specific role from the Candidates Page:**
>
> 1. Choose a job
> 2. Select all candidates by selecting the checkbox at the top left
> 3. Select Export Candidates

This help article indicates the same (including screenshots): https://help.wizehire.com/en/articles/2565110-how-do-i-export-candidates-from-my-indeed-account

However, when I select my job and candidates, I don't see an export button..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable 2-Step Verification before it will show. They recently added this step.